# Question:What is the difference between filter method and mask in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

what is the difference between filter method and mask in numPy?

Comment: numpy doesn't have either filter or mask method

Comment: Provide more context for you question.  While we often refer to a boolean array as a mask, and use it to fetch or select elements from an array, the term 'filter' is less common.  It is used with respect to lists and 'itertools', but there isn't a standardized `numpy` usage (or function/method).

Answer (score 1):

The filter will return only values which match the filter condition, but the mask returns the result for the condition.
mask:

`a = np.arange(4)
    ma.masked_where(a == 2, a)
    mask = [False False  True False]`

filter :

```
a[np.where( a == 2 )]   
array([2])
```